# How to reflect JStree changes to the original XML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-ui

I'm using JStree to display an XML file, and after displaying it the user can create, rename, or delete some nodes, and sor sure these changes appear only on the displayed xml and not reflected on the original file, I want to know how to reflect this changes to the original XML fie back after clicking like a submit button, or at least how to get the data changed.

**Update**

**The code:**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>menu-editor</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jstree/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jstree/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jstree/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<link href="themes/!style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jstree/!script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/UIMTreeProcessor.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
.
.
.
//css stuff
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="dummy"></div>
<div id="mylist">
<li id='root'><a href='#'>Root node</a><ul><li><a href='#'>Child node</a></li></ul></li>
</div>

<div id="submit" class="submit_btn">Submit</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" class="source below">
var _url = "cafe.xml";
        var _uimTree = null;

        $(function () {
            getTopContent();
        });

        getTopContent = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: _url,
                dataType:"xml",
                cache: false,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    //do something before send
                },
                success: function(data){
                    processXML(data);
                },
                error:function(e){
                    alert("Error: "+e);
                }
            });
        }       

        processXML = function(root){
            _uimTree = new UIMTreeProcessor(root, $("#mylist"));
            _uimTree.doProcess(); 


        }


$('#submit').on('click',function(){ 

      //alert the entire XML after edits via (getXML)

});

</script>
```

*And the **UIMtreeprocessor** Library code*

```
function UIMTreeProcessor(data, treeEl) {
    this.data = data;
    this.treeEl = treeEl;
}

UIMTreeProcessor.prototype.initTree = function(data){
    this.treeEl.jstree({
        "json_data" : {
            "data":data,
            "progressive_render":"true"
        },
        "plugins" : ["themes","json_data","ui","crrm","cookies","dnd","search","types","hotkeys","contextmenu"],
        "core":{"animation":0}
        });
}

UIMTreeProcessor.prototype.doProcess = function(){
    //Find root:
    var _root = $(this.data).children(':first-child');
    var _a_feed = new Array();

    this.vsTraverse($(_root), _a_feed);

    var _treedata = [{"data":_root[0].nodeName,"children":_a_feed, "state":"open"}];
    this.initTree(_treedata);
}

UIMTreeProcessor.prototype.vsTraverse = function(node, arr){
    var _ch = $(node).children();

    for(var i=0; i<_ch.length; i++){
        var _vsArr = new Array();
        this.vsTraverse(_ch[i], _vsArr);
        var _a_att = this.vsTraverseAtt(_ch[i]);
        if(null!=_a_att){
            _vsArr.push([{"data":"Attributes "+"["+_ch[i].nodeName+"]","children":_a_att, attr : { "class" : "uim_attr"}}]);
        }
        if(null!=_ch[i].firstChild && 3==_ch[i].firstChild.nodeType){
            arr.push([{"data":_ch[i].nodeName + ": " + _ch[i].firstChild.textContent,"children":_vsArr, "state":"open"}]);
        }else{
            arr.push([{"data":_ch[i].nodeName,"children":_vsArr, "state":"open"}]);
        }

    }
}

UIMTreeProcessor.prototype.vsTraverseAtt = function(node){
    var _a_atts = null;
    if(null!=node.attributes && node.attributes.length > 0){
        _a_atts = new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<node.attributes.length; i++){
            _a_atts.push(node.attributes[i].nodeName + ":" + node.attributes[i].nodeValue);
        }
    }
    return _a_atts;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I was really wrong in my original answer.

There is a `get_xml` method in the [xml_data](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data) plugin, which is supposed to do what you describe. I have not tested it myself, but if it's anything like `json_data.getJSON`, the output will contain all kinds of JStree metadata which you will not want to put back into your XML.

Comment: i found it in the documentation but can't find in the plugin

Comment: I had misspelled the method name. Can you find it now?

Comment: No, is there's some steps i do to add the xml_data plugin ? or adding the jstree is enough

Comment: You must load the plugin in your config. `.jstree({ plugins : [ "xml_data", "some-other-plugin" ... ] });`

Comment: do you have an idea about the whole expression used in this case ? like am i suppose to call it from another place ?

Comment: `$("my-tree-selector").jstree("get_xml")` doesn't work? or `$.jstree._focused().get_xml()`... or from inside an event handler `data.inst.get_xml()`

Comment: i'll just upload my full code and if you can check it for me it 'll be great

Comment: I don't see `xml_data` in your list of plugins. You have `"plugins" : ["themes","json_data","ui","crrm","cookies","dnd","search","types","hotkeys","contextmenu"]`.